# Add option to GDM 3.x that does not have gui

Tags: ubuntu, bash, debian, gdm

You know how when you login with GDM, and you can select a variety of desktop environments? For instance, mine has `Cinnamon, GNOME 3, xfce`. How could I add an option that logs you in *without* a gui? (It should be similar to changing `/etc/default/grub` to make the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`, that sort of non-gui.) Is this even possible to do?

EDIT: I am running `Zen Linux 1.0-rc1`, a variety of `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Answer (score 0):

Not, this is not possible. When you see the `gdm` login window you're already in GUI mode  and it is not possible to *not* use that mode when logging in via `gdm`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to the console, you can then login like you'd when appending `text` to the kernel commandline.